# Различие между @MainThread и @UiThread

Tags: android, аннотации, android-annotations, androidx

[В документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#thread-annotations) по поводу различия между аннотациями @MainThread и @UiThread написано следующее:

> The build tools treat the @MainThread and @UiThread annotations as
>   interchangeable, so you can call @UiThread methods from @MainThread
>   methods, and vice versa. However, it's possible for a UI thread to be
>   different from the main thread in the case of system apps with
>   multiple views on different threads. Therefore, you should annotate
>   methods associated with an app's view hierarchy with @UiThread and
>   annotate only methods associated with an app's lifecycle with
>   @MainThread.

Насколько я понимаю, это переводится так:

> Инструменты сборки рассматривают аннотации @MainThread и @UiThread как
>   взаимозаменяемые, поэтому вы можете вызывать методы, помеченные @UiThread из
>   методов, помеченных @MainThread, и наоборот. Тем не менее, UI поток 
>   может отличаться от main потока в случае системных
>   приложений с несколькими представлениями в разных потоках.
>   Следовательно, вы должны аннотировать методы, связанные с иерархией
>   представлений приложения, с помощью @UiThread, и только
>   методы, связанные с жизненным циклом приложения, аннотировать с помощью
>   @MainThread.

А что это за системные приложения с несколькими представлениями в разных потоках? Применительно к андроид платформе это же невозможно, чтобы представления были не в main (или UI) потоке?

Comment: интересный вопрос. [по теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784584/difference-between-the-main-thread-and-ui-thread)

Comment: @TimurVI, спасибо!